# Mailgun throw fatal error instead of exception for PHP SDK

Tags: php, mailgun

I'm trying to implement Mailgun API serive for handle my emails, this is my code according to the documentation:

index.php

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Mailgun\Mailgun;

$mgClient = Mailgun::create("key-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"); 
$domain = "xxxxxxx.com"; 


$mgClient->sendMessage($domain, 
                       array('from' => 'Dwight Schrute<dwight@xxxxxxx.com>', 
                             'to' => 'Michael Scott <xxxx@xxxxx.com>', 
                             'subject' => 'The Printer Caught Fire', 
                             'text' => 'We have a problem.'));

var_dump($result);
```

composer.json

```
 "require": {
        "mailgun/mailgun-php": "^2.3",
        "php-http/curl-client": "^1.7",
        "guzzlehttp/psr7": "^1.4"
    }
```

everything works fine but $result contains tons of data instead of simple return array with id and message "message was queued thank you". Another problem is when I simulate error to see what happen, unfortunately Mailgun make fatal error instead of connection exception which I can handle:

```
[30-Nov-2017 10:05:44 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Mailgun\Connection\Exceptions\MissingRequiredParameters' with message 'The parameters passed to the API were invalid. Check your inputs! Free accounts are for test purposes only. Please upgrade or add the address to authorized recipients in Account Settings.' in /home/xxx/xxx/vendor/mailgun/mailgun-php/src/Mailgun/Connection/RestClient.php:254
Stack trace:
#0 /home/xxx/xxx/vendor/mailgun/mailgun-php/src/Mailgun/Connection/RestClient.php(110): Mailgun\Connection\RestClient->responseHandler(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response))
#1 /home/xxx/xxx/vendor/mailgun/mailgun-php/src/Mailgun/Connection/RestClient.php(179): Mailgun\Connection\RestClient->send('POST', 'xxxxx.com...', Array, Array)
#2 /home/xxx/xxx/vendor/mailgun/mailgun-php/src/Mailgun/Mailgun.php(204): Mailgun\Connection\RestClient->post('xxxxx.com...', Array, Array)
#3 /home/xxx/xxx/vendor/mailgun/mailgun-php/src/Mailgun/Mailgun.php(135): Mailgun\Mailgun->post(' in /home/xxxxxx/vendor/mailgun/mailgun-php/src/Mailgun/Connection/RestClient.php on line 254
```

I'm using PHP 7 os linux no framework. What I'm doing wrong? Thanks for any advice.

Comment: What do you mean? It is throwing an exception as it states pretty clearly in the error message. You are not catching it so it results in a fatal error.

Comment: @boosterV [catch](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.catch.php) it

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs whenever utilizing either a sandbox domain or a free account without inviting users called Authorized Recipients. Free plans are intended for test usage and all custom domains require Authorized Recipients. With upgraded plans, custom domains no longer require Authorized Recipients.

Please take a look at the following Help Center article for more information about the Authorized Recipient process:

https://help.mailgun.com/hc/en-us/articles/217531258-Authorized-Recipients

For more information on upgrading, please review:

https://help.mailgun.com/hc/en-us/articles/203599840-How-do-I-upgrade-my-account-

*Disclaimer I work at Mailgun*

Comment: Thank you Nolan for your response, yes I know that, as I said I made this error on purpose to see how script will behave. I will use try catch block for exceptions. Is it normal that while using PHP SDK to sending messages I get tons of data instead of simple return array with id and message "message was queued thank you"?